# Как создать анимацию покадрового появления галочки

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

у меня есть картинка.Мне нужно сделать анимацию по которой галочка покадрово появится 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .9em;
}
.example-1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #ddaa55;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.example-1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(http://iconspot.ru/files/175351.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: width .5s;
}
.example-1:hover:after {
  width: 50px;
}
.example-2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #ddaa55;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.example-2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(http://iconspot.ru/files/175351.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: .5s linear 0s infinite alternate check;
}
@keyframes check {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to: {
    width: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>При помощи <code>transition</code>. Можно использовать при смене состояния и с добавлением класса (наведите курсор):</p>
<div class="example-1"></div>

<p>При помощи <code>animation</code>. Можно использовать как при смене состояния или с добавлением класса, так и без какого-либо события:</p>
<div class="example-2"></div>
```

[Свойство `transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

[Использование CSS анимации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Ispolzovanie_CSS_animatciy)

Comment: Подскажите а как сделать так чтобы анимация выполнилась один только раз(напримере второй анимации)

Comment: @vasily_dumov убрать параметр `infinite`. А еще прочитайте статью, ссылку на которую я привел в ответе. Там подробно рассказывается о различных вариантах применения анимации и о необходимых вендерных префиксах у свойств для лучшей поддержки браузерами.